# XKeymacs: how to bind to C-S-s?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, key-binding

I'm trying to make [XKeymacs](http://xkeymacs.osdn.jp/) translate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> key binding to VisualStudio's `File.SaveAll` command. But I can't find the correct notation of this key binding.

So far I've tried several options, including the following ones:

- `[?\C-\S-s]`
- `[?\Ctrl-\Shift-s]`
- `"?\Ctrl-\Shift-s"`
- `[?\Ctrl+S]`
- `[?\S-\C-s]`

Could you suggest me the right one, please? Or, if you're not familiar XKeymacs, some options I could try to find the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `[?\Ctrl+S-s]` should do the trick.